# How to make the keyboard instantly show?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have a view in which i a have a text field. I want to know how I can make the keyboard appear directly when the view appears witouth having to click on anything.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Thank you rmaddy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `viewDidAppear` call `becomeFirstResponder` on the text field.